# Getting max of first 100 elements in a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector of 1,000 elements. What's the fastest way to obtain the maximum of the first 100 elements in R?

Currently I'm doing `maximum_value <- max(my_values[1:100])` and this works fine. Is there a faster way?

Comment: if it works, why fix it?

Comment: Simple answer: use C. Or Fortran

Comment: I suspect you're really interested in doing this on a different scale; as stands, this takes on average 1.7 microseconds on my computer. If this is substantially different on your machine, you need a new processor first. If you're really interested in doing this on a different scale, please edit the question to reflect something closer to what you've actually got in mind.

Comment: What is the structure / contents of `my_values`? Are the numeric, integers? Is `1:100` truly magical? Like previously mentioned, does this operation need to be repeated? There is a strong reason to suspect that your example might be a bit too minimal! That being said, `max` is primitive already. Should be fast! Is the subsetting the slow part?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of comparison, I tried the following, and your answer remains the fastest.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
x <- runif(1000)
xdt <- data.table(x)

microbenchmark(max(x[1:100]), max(x[-c(101:1000)]),max(head(x,100)),xdt[1:100,max(x)])
Unit: microseconds
                 expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
        max(x[1:100])   1.090   1.4385   2.50614   2.0365   2.9890   14.402   100
 max(x[-c(101:1000)])   6.724   9.6775  11.59118  10.6460  12.2560   42.700   100
    max(head(x, 100))   8.600  10.9975  15.06039  14.3295  17.0845   39.316   100
   xdt[1:100, max(x)] 266.587 285.3405 385.43024 296.0390 314.0550 7345.151   100
```